# How do I parse this variable containing \n?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, node.js, mongodb

I have a really weird number in my mongoDB document. I copied the whole object over to the  `node` console. I'm outputting it here. I'm thinking it has a combination of string `\n`'s and actual textual `\n`'s  or something weird going on. Can someone tell me how to just get the number   `567899876545678987654` as a string, out of the variable below?

```
> number
'--- \n- "567899876545678987654"\n- \n'
> JSON.stringify(number);
'"--- \\n- \\"567899876545678987654\\"\\n- \\n"'
> number.replace("\n","");
'--- - "567899876545678987654"\n- \n'
> number.replace(/\n/,"");
'--- - "567899876545678987654"\n- \n'
> number.replace(/-/,"");
'-- \n- "567899876545678987654"\n- \n'
```

Comment: `+/\d+/.exec( number )[ 0 ];`

Comment: The `replace` method only replaces the first instance.  You need `number.replace(/\n/g, "")` to replace all instances of `\n`.

Comment: @jAndy returns `9.405510200828548e+21` as an `int`. I want string.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: just omit the leading `+` then.

Comment: `/\d+/.exec(number)[0];` works. Any reason to use it over `number.match(/\d+/)[0]`? Same thing right?

Comment: `.exec` is slightly faster :) http://jsperf.com/match-vs-exec24

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a regex for all digits instead of trying to remove the rest?

```
actualNumber = number.match(/\d+/);
```

As T.J. Crowder points out, `actualNumber` will now be an array containing the number (**if** there was one). As he suggests, this will safely retrieve the actual number:

```
var m = number.match(/\d+/);
if (m) { 
    actualNumber = m[0];
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `var m = number.match(/\d+/); if (m) { actualNumber = m[0]; }` On the theory that @ThomasReggi doesn't want an array.

Comment: rawsome! was missing `/g` though.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: You don't need `/g` with your sample input.

Comment: I was using `replace` and `number.replace(/\n|-|\s/g,"");` got me close.